# Cassandra service not starting

Tags: cassandra

Im trying to start cassandra but dont see any response.

```
hduser@vagrant:~/cassandra/apache-cassandra-2.1.12-src/bin$ cassandra -f
hduser@vagrant:~/cassandra/apache-cassandra-2.1.12-src/bin$
```

I have downloaded cassandra in this folder -

```
/home/hduser/cassandra/apache-cassandra-2.1.12-src
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you downloaded the source distribution of cassandra, try downloading the binary ('bin') distribution instead from the [download page](http://cassandra.apache.org/download/).

Otherwise, you can compile the source distribution using [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) by running `ant` from the root directory of the extracted archive and then running cassandra per usual.